# iText v5 unicode and ColdFusion

Tags: unicode, coldfusion, itext

I am using `iText v5` in **ColdFusion 9** and want to include the `CopyRight` symbol. The docs and books says to pass the `unicode` string eg `\u00a9`. What I am getting back is that string, not the symbol. Here is my test case:

```
// Ask iText what version it is. This include the Registered and Copyright symbols so this
// font can obviously display them
vers = variables.javaLoader.create("com.itextpdf.text.Version").getVersion();

// Make a new paragraph and add the version number to the document
vPara = variables.javaLoader.create("com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph").init(vers);
myDoc1.add(vPara);

// Make a new string including the CopyRight symbol as per the iText docs and book
str = CreateObject("java","java.lang.String").init('Acme Products\u00a9');

// Make another paragraph and add the string to the document 
para = variables.javaLoader.create("com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph").init(str);
myDoc1.add(para);
```

and this is the output (copied fom the pdf):

```
iText® 5.4.1 ©2000-2012 1T3XT BVBA
Acme Products\u00a9
```

Notice the the Registered and Copyright symbols appear correctly in the version string so the font can display them.

I am thinking I am missing something really basic here but cant see it. I know I don't really need to create my own `java.lang.String` since that is what CF does anyway but just to eliminate that possibility I went that far.

Comment: What happens if you just do `str = CreateObject("java","java.lang.String").init('Acme Products®');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chr(169) instead of \u00a9.
May be look like below.

```
str = CreateObject("java","java.lang.String").init('Acme Products#chr(169)#');
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. And, to be complete:

 str = "Trademark"  & chr( InputBaseN( '2122', 16 ) );
 str = "Registered" & chr( InputBaseN( '00AE', 16 ) );
 str = "Copyright"  & chr( InputBaseN( '00A9', 16 ) );

Answer (score 2):

@Pritesh Patel

Thanks! That was it. And, to be complete for unicode (since I wanted the TradeMark too):

```
str = "Trademark"  & chr( InputBaseN( '2122', 16 ) );
str = "Registered" & chr( InputBaseN( '00AE', 16 ) );
str = "Copyright"  & chr( InputBaseN( '00A9', 16 ) );
```

In other words, CHR() handles unicode too. Codes are available here: http://www.unicode.org/

Murray